# installing Dompdf in windows

Tags: dompdf

i install DOMPDF by composer but when i tried to run this code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
'<html><body>'.
'<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
'templating system.</p>'.
'</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

it gives me this FatalErrorException  Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' 
i change DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD to be false

i guess i install DOMPDF wrong so how to install it for windows step by step
or how to solve this problem

Comment: The error indicates that the path to vendor/autoload.php is incorrect. Make sure the path is correct relative to the executing PHP file. To be certain you're using the correct path you might try using the full path to the composer autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

```
Setting up the Dompdf (a pdf generation package in php) in XAMPP in windows environment can sometimes be an issue.
```

The error message is due to the conflict between the internal extensions.So you need to disbale the Domdocument extension from the configuraion file.`extension = php_domxml.dll`

`dompdf uses PDFLib by default if it is available in the system and PDFLib is a commercial package which is not available by default in the system but its extention is enabled in php.ini by default in the system.`

Please have a look [here](http://www.diademblogs.com/phpmysql/setting-up-and-getting-dompdf-to-work-in-xampp-on-windows)